# Creating a pop up dialog alert

Tags: swift

I'm trying to create a popup uialert sort of to create a confirmation box. I have a button in ViewControllerTwo and when pressed navigates back to ViewControllerOne, however I want to create a popup message that asks to confirm (Yes or No) if I really want to navigate to ViewControllerOne. If yes it goes backs to ViewOne, if no it stays on the ViewTwo. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
@IBAction func showAlertTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        //Create the AlertController
        let myAlertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Hey..!", message: "Are You sure to Do some stuff??", preferredStyle: .Alert)

        //Create and add the Cancel action
        let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { action -> Void in
            //Do some stuff
        }
        myAlertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        //Create and an option action
        let nextAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Next", style: .Default) { action -> Void in


       let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Storyboard", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
       let vc : UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("vcMainLogin") as UIViewController
       self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        myAlertController.addAction(nextAction)


        //Present the AlertController
        self.presentViewController(myAlertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: It works, but it doesnt navigate to the next ViewController. Im trying to get the button to change views if "Yes" is hit and if "NO" is hit it should stay on the same ViewController

Comment: @Fogmeister, What am i supposed to explain?
I don't understand

Comment: Sorry. Just saw the comments.

Comment: @Fogmeister if my answer is useful , you should upVote.
Thanks